# Why no item images in my RSS

Tags: rss

I'm trying to add images to my RSS feed items. I've read the common way to do it is not enclose description in CDATA and add html img tag inside.
I've done it but I can see no result. Looking at my feed with Feedly or GReader on my phone but still no images are there.

Here's my [feed url](https://my.miit.ru/rss).

It is valid according to [W3C](http://feedvalidator.org/check.cgi?url=https%3A//my.miit.ru/rss).

Here's an item code:

```
<item><title> item title </title>
<link><![CDATA[http://miit.ru/cp?id_page=1825&id_pi=1824&view_mode=1.3&id_info=134354]]></link>
<guid isPermaLink="true"><![CDATA[http://miit.ru/cp?id_page=1825&id_pi=1824&view_mode=1.3&id_info=134354]]></guid>
<description><![CDATA[<img src="http://miit.ru/content/DSC_0017.jpg?id_wm=719704&SWidth=120"/><br/> item desc ]]></description>
<pubDate>Fri, 22 Nov 2013 16:02:00 GMT</pubDate>
</item>
```

You can see the description tag with cdata and image.
Link and guid are in CData because validator doesn't like & symbol.

Any ideas why no item images?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the  option : `<heigth>` to your rss image.

Default is 31. Maximum value is 400.

Your image looks large and heavy.

Hope this helps you.

Anyway, I tested your code [here](http://www.w3schools.com/rss/tryrss.asp?filename=rss_ex_guid) and i get an image.